# Regarding the usage of ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)

Tags: knockout.js

It seems that the `ko.toJSON()` method will convert something to json string.

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

but I do not understand what is `$data` because it is never declared or used in code. You can see my full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7e0vujf5/11/

Why is the second argument `null` and what is the meaning of 2nd as 3rd argument?

Comment: `$data` refers to your current context . so in your case it refers to looping context i.e it will print all the data `lines` having . cheers

Comment: @supercool i have one small request. can come with few small example which will show usage of $data in different context. suppose i want to print main view model data in json format or nested one view model data.....how to achieve it. thanks

Comment: sure mate give me some time i'm in middle of something now. once i get time i will post a sample for you by EOD

Comment: @supercool thanks u. suppose people can work with 4/5 view model may be not all active at same time....so in that kind of situation how to print json version of data by $data. waiting for your answer and take your time....no problem.........thanks a lot

Comment: Actually that `ko.toJSON` we use for testing purposes i.e to check whether it is properly looping or not . try this sample http://jsfiddle.net/7e0vujf5/13/ which explains dealing with 2 vms . `$data` always refers to current context  don't get confused its very simple . in your case `lines` & `$data` content are same .

Comment: @supercool thanks i understand the usage :)

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is a special Knockout [binding context variable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) which is only available inside `data-bind` expressions and it always refers to the view model object in the current context.

The other two parameter controls the [`JSON.stringify()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which is eventually called by `ko.toJSON`

Where `null` is the **replacer** fuction:

> A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for selecting the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.

And the 2 is the **space**:

> A String or Number object that's used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes.